# Accessing a uinavigationbar from subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a subclass based on UIView and i want to change the tint of the uinavigationbar but various methods I've tried haven't worked. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the view is in a viewController that's part of the navigation stack you can do:

```
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

To access the viewController, you can declare an id as an ivar in your View class:

```
id myParentViewController;
```

Declare this id as a property so it can be accessed from outside the View.

When creating the view from the viewController, you could pass a reference to the viewController into the view by doing:

```
view.myParentViewController = self;
```

Where `self` would be the reference to your viewController on the navigation stack.

Now that you're in the view, you can access the navigation bar by doing this:

```
if([myParentViewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
    {
        UIViewController *theParentViewController = (UIViewController*)myParentViewController;
        theParentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access UINavigationBar from UINavigationController. One method is pass the UINavigationController or UINavigationBar as a parameter to the UIView. Or the UIView can use delegate to notify the outer UIViewController to do works.